# How to simplify the size of the equation using predefined variables in maple?

Tags: maple, algebra-precalculus

I am working on some simple calculations using maple for my assignment. I have an equation say $x=a$, I assigned it in maple like
$$x:=a$$
Later in my calculation I got some $y$ as

$$y=a^2+\sin(a)$$

I need $y$ in terms of $x$ not in $a$ like $y=x^2+\sin(x)$.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Explain precisely what it means, that you later "got some y as...". How exactly was that expression later obtained? Provide the specific plaintext commands which reproduce your results in full.

Comment: I have defined $n(y)$ and $v$ as
$$n(y):=\sqrt{\frac{b}{\nu}}*y$$
$$v := -sqrt(b*\nu)*f(n(y))$$.

Now I have calculated $diff(v, y)$
I am getting
$-bD(f)(\sqrt\frac{b}{\nu}*y)$
But I need this one as $-bD(f)(n(y))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to execute the assignment `x:=a;` in order to utilize an equation like `x=a`.

Similarly, you don't have to execute the assignment `n:=(y -> sqrt(b/v)*y);` in order to utilize that as a definition of an operator for `n`.

The same thing goes for 2D Input syntax, where you don't need to execute the assignment `n(y):=sqrt(b/v)*y;` in order to utilize that as a definition for `n` as an operator.

In other words, if these assignments are getting in your way, then simply *don't make them*. You can use similar *equations* instead of those *assignments*. And you can even utilize them *selectively*, so that they don't affect all your computations.

For your first example, you can produce either form, with `a` or with `x`.

```
restart;

defn1 := x = a:

y := x^2 + sin(x):
```

Now `y` is in terms of just `x`.

```
y;

             2         
            x  + sin(x)
```

And you don't need to produce the following (unless you want to),

```
eval(y, defn1);

             2         
            a  + sin(a)
```

Let's look at your followup example.

The same technique from the earlier example can be used.

```
restart;
defn := n = (y -> sqrt(b/v)*y):
nu := -sqrt(b*v)*f(n(y)):
```

Notice that we have *not* assigned anything to `n`.

```
raw := diff(nu,y);

                     (1/2)            / d      \
        raw := -(b v)      D(f)(n(y)) |--- n(y)|
                                      \ dy     /
```

We can make a new equation from `defn`,

```
new := diff(n(y),y) = eval(diff(n(y),y), defn);

                                    (1/2)
                       d         /b\     
               new := --- n(y) = |-|     
                       dy        \v/
```

Again, we have not assigned anything to `n`. But we can re-evaluate the result `raw` above and utilize the `new` equation to make a replacement (substitution).

```
ans := eval(raw, new);

                                          (1/2)
                      (1/2)            /b\     
         ans := -(b v)      D(f)(n(y)) |-|     
                                       \v/
```

I suspect that you have omitted some assumptions that `b` and `v` are both positive. Under those assumptions the radicals in the result `ans` will simplify, and we have a choice of commands that will do that.

```
combine(ans) assuming b>0, v>0;

                     -b D(f)(n(y))

simplify(ans) assuming b>0, v>0;

                     -b D(f)(n(y))
```

The moral of the story is this: don't make assignments that you don't want. You can use the `eval` command with `equations` to perform selective substitution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writing. It is worked.